# Meaning of オレンジ in オレンジは右側です

Tags: meaning

I couldn't find the answer to this.

Sometimes when I'm on the subway in Japan when getting close to the next stop in some trains it can be heard **オレンジは右側です**, not sure if it's **オレンジ** though. Meaning the exit is on the right or left side, any clue if it's saying **オレンジ** or anything else? If **オレンジ** is being said, why orange?

Comment: I can confirm that there is a specific recording used on some trains (山手線 at least IIRC) that truly sounds like オレンジ (or オレンチ, which is also amusing). It might be interesting to post a seperate question with a link to audio, asking *why* it sounds like that (presumably only to us non-native speakers...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are probably saying:

> お出口{でぐち}は右側です

Meaning, of course, the exit is on the right.

Comment: They not, some subways says that, but other says **オレンジ* or something similar. Google "オレンジは右側です" and you will see some sites with that phrase, of course, everything in Japanese so I couldn't catch everything

Comment: LOL It seems I'm not the only one, look at this [tweet](https://twitter.com/Woopa0101/status/852778217081413633?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E852778217081413633&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Firorio.jp%2Fjpn_manatee%2F20170419%2F396865%2F)

Comment: That tweet confirms what Blavius is saying - check out this link in the comments - https://irorio.jp/jpn_manatee/20170419/396865/

Comment: Gotcha! LOL, sometimes it really sounds like **オレンジ** instead of　お出口